# Pass email as regex in django url

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I am trying to pass email as parameter in django URL. I want to pass email as well as normal string and number also in URL as arguments.

```
url(r"search_connections/(?P<data>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$", "search_connections", name="search_connections"),
```

It's working properly for email as a parameter. But for normal string like "abc" it's not working:

```
working for "/search_connections/abc@test.com/"
not working for "/search_connections/abc/"
```

I want this URL to work for both.

Comment: The `@` is not allowed in the path of a URL and many clients consider everything between `://` and `@` the username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try simply use `|` (or) with `\w+`:

```
r'search_connections/(?P<data>\w+|[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$'
```

However I think regex for email just isn't a robust solution to match all valid emails.

Comment: \w+ compromised the purpose of email regex