# Referencing User ID in Django URL dispatcher

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to implement a search feature where user's can search an email on a React frontend and it'll return that email's top 5 love languages. Currently the url path requires the primary key of a love language model, but I want it to use the user id. I have this Django URL set as:

```py
path('love-languages/', LovesView.as_view(), name='love-languages'),
path('love-languages/<int:pk>', LoveView.as_view(), name='love-languages')
```

Relevant love language model:

```py
class Love(models.Model):
    # Obtaining the user from the user model
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )
    
    # Defining the dropdown choices 
    class LoveLanguages(models.TextChoices):
        ACTS_OF_SERVICE = 'Acts of Service'
        RECEIVING_GIFTS = 'Receiving Gifts'
        QUALITY_TIME = 'Quality Time'
        WORDS_OF_AFFIRMATION = 'Words of Affirmation'
        PHYSICAL_TOUCH = 'Physical Touch'
    
    one = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LoveLanguages.choices)
    two = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LoveLanguages.choices)
    three = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LoveLanguages.choices)
    four = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LoveLanguages.choices)
    five = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LoveLanguages.choices)
```

and love language views:

```py
class LovesView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        loves = Love.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
        data = LoveSerializer(loves, many=True).data
        return Response(data)
    
    def post(self, request):
        request.data['user'] = request.user.id
        love = LoveSerializer(data=request.data)
        if love.is_valid():
            love.save()
            return Response(love.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(love.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class LoveView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        love = get_object_or_404(Love, pk=pk)
        # if request.user != love.user:
        #     raise PermissionDenied('Unauthorized, you are not signed in as this user')
        # else:
        data = LoveSerializer(love).data
        return Response(data)
    def delete(self, request, pk):
        love = get_object_or_404(Love, pk=pk)
        if request.user != love.user:
            raise PermissionDenied('Unauthorized, you are not signed in as this user')
        else:
            love.delete()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
    def put(self, request, pk):
        love = get_object_or_404(Love, pk=pk)
        if request.user != love.owner:
            raise PermissionDenied('Unauthorized, you are not signed in as this user')
        else:
            updated_love = LoveSerializer(love, data=request.data)
        if updated_love.is_valid():
            updated_love.save()
            return Response(updated_love.data)
        else:
            return Response(love.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So, if this were the data returned:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "user": 2,
    "one": "Acts of Service",
    "two": "Receiving Gifts",
    "three": "Quality Time",
    "four": "Words of Affirmation",
    "five": "Physical Touch"
}
```

The URL would have to be .../love-languages/4. I want the URL to be .../love-languages/2 because I am not sure how I can access the pk of 4 when only an email is entered. I've thought about referencing the love language model in the user model, but I think there should be a way to replace <int:pk> in the URL with something like <int:user>? I tried that and it did not work, I got an error saying `TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'` I was reading the django docs for URL dispatcher but couldn't find anything useful at the moment.

I also tried changing the get request in the views to

```py
 love = get_object_or_404(Love, pk=request.user.id)
```

but that didn't work. It only returns the same data regardless of what id is entered in the url.

Comment: I think first you have to query your user model to find which user that email belongs to. then use that user in a query to find the love instance belonging to that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly here is what you need to do.
Django allows you to query a model and its relationship with `__`.

So to make a query about Love model with respect to user you would do something like this.

```
try:
    love = Love.objects.get(user__email=variable_email)
except Love.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
```

there are 2 ways to detect email in url.
you can simply use `<str:variable_email>` and then clean the email in you view before using it to query your database.
or you can use regex to detect in url pattern.( like question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740171/pass-email-as-regex-in-django-url))